# Liquibase 3.5.0 updateSQL command generates SQL Server output with catalog name

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

There is a difference on the `updateSQL` command on Liquibase 3.4.2 and 3.5.0 for SQL Server database.

By default, 3.4.2 version generates the command like this (without catalog name):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DR_DATABASECHANGELOG] ([ID] [int] NOT NULL
```

But, on 3.5.0 the command became like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dev].[dbo].[DR_DATABASECHANGELOG] ([ID] [int] NOT NULL
```

I tried to turn catalog name off using outputDefaultCatalog property, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to get rid of the catalog name on the generated SQL script ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug with 3.5.0 where it is too agressive in including the catalog/database name. I created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2750 to track the fix, which should go out with 3.5.1 in the next couple days.